# Maudlin's Twin Paradox (Both observers accelerate)

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration

This is taken from *[The twin paradox: the role of acceleration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02148)* by J. Gamboa,F. Mendez,M. B. Paranjape, and Benoit Sirois:
[image]

> Maudlin modifies the circumstances of the twin para-
> dox by considering a situation, where twin A undergoes
> one small period of accelerated motion at the middle of
> the journey, characterized by a triangular “bump” on the
> Minkowski diagram of the frame of the original twin A
> (see Figure (5)).

> It is clear that the acceleration of A can be equal to or even greater than the acceleration of B.
> However, because A’s worldline is still longer than B’s, A
> ends up older than B, even though A underwent an equal
> or greater amount of acceleration. Maudlin’s conclusion
> then is that acceleration plays no role in the resolution
> of the twin paradox.

> But where is the paradox in this case? The motion
> of the two twins is in no sense symmetric. There is no
> symmetry argument that one could make that would lead
> to a paradox. Simply we would have to do the calcula-
> tion of the elapsed proper time of each twin according
> to each twin and find the obvious fact that twin B ends
> up younger.

> It is true that when analyzing the problem from the
> frame of reference of twin A, one can neglect the length
> of the accelerating part of the travelling twin’s worldline,
> when it is much shorter than the coasting part (as in
> Fig(4)), and one does of course find the travelling twin
> B to be younger. But the presence of acceleration is
> necessary in even coming up with a paradox at all. This
> is why introducing multiple periods of accelerations is
> specious, it has no bearing on the original paradox.

The justifications seem hard to follow for me. Despite the fact that the situation is not symmetric, both observers will agree on seeing the other observer speed away, stop moving for a brief moment, and then travel back to the origin.
It does seem that each observer will perceive the other to be older. This was resolved as in the original statement of the paradox this symmetry is broken by one observer who is "actually" accelerating and the other isn't, but this becomes unclear here since both observers perform acceleration for the same proper time.
The paper suggests that even for such a scenario to arise the presence of acceleration is a necessity, but what is the justification for A to be younger than B in reality, when A and B meet?
The proper time calculations provide us the correct answer here as well, but what causes it to be correct?

Comment: The authors completely fail to explain what "problem" they are solving.  They even acknowledge the "version" where both twins are inertial the whole time!  Maybe someone else can see the merit of the pages of mathematics.  I'll stick to the "two lines of algebra" solution thanks very much!

Comment: Some observations: 1) "Tim Maudlin is professor of _philosophy_ at New York University. " - IOW wrong subject area!  2) "Requires only basic algebra and no formal knowledge of physics" - IOW don't bother using this to learn anything "formal".  Shame on you Tim Maudlin!

Comment: This (apologies to the sensitive) "baby problem" causes such noise hereabouts, and the name is so genuinely misleading that I think I will start to refer to it in future posts as the _"Terrible Twins"_.  Any better suggestions?

Comment: @m4r35n357 Maudlin's Terrible Twins...

Answer (score 2):

> both observers will agree on seeing the other observer speed away, stop moving for a brief moment, and then travel back to the origin

This is not correct. At least not in a reference frame that respects the second postulate. Unfortunately, people often have an incorrect understanding of non-inertial reference frames.

For example, in the standard twin’s paradox, people often think that the traveling twin sees the home twin just go out and back. In fact, in the traveling twin’s frame, the home twin’s worldline goes out, at the relative velocity, accelerates once to become stationary, and accelerates a second time to begin closing at the relative velocity.

See figure 9 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0104077

> what is the justification for A to be younger than B in reality, when A and B meet?

It is the same as always. A’s path through spacetime is shorter than B’s. You integrate the spacetime metric along each twin’s worldline to get the length of their path through spacetime. This is their proper time. This works for any worldline in any spacetime

Comment: There is no doubt whatsoever that the proper time calculations provide the mathematical solution. My confusion lies in the reason why it comes out to be so, since both observers undergo acceleration.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker That is the reason why people are telling you that the Twin Paradox is an SR phenomenon. The time difference is linearly proportional to the amount of time spent travelling on the constant velocity parts. The acceleration helps us figure out which side gets which aging, but otherwise, it is purely a Minkowski geometry problem.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker the "TP" arises _directly_ from the Lorentz Transform (or, equivalently, the Minkowski spacetime metric).  _Neither of these_ contains an acceleration term.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker you are missing the point. The point is that the proper time is a length. The length has little to do with the acceleration, which is the bend. You are saying “the bend is the same”, and I am pointing out that the length is different.

Comment: @m4r35n357 and Dale We seems to be at loggerheads, so just to be clear IMO it seems that one of the bodies needs to accelerate in order for such a situation to arise in the first place. With this is mind, I want to clarify the statement "A’s path through spacetime is shorter than B’s."
When we say this, we are performing the calculations with a preferred frame, as doing the same calculations in B's frame will give us the opposite answer. My biggest confusion lies in whether we are performing the proper time calculations with a preferred frame as well in Maudlin's case.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker The key to the _Terrible Twins_ is that the situation is _not_ symmetrical.  Truly.  One  of the blighters deviates from geodesic motion, and the other does not, although the effect can be "simulated" by passing messages with no acceleration.  If you haven't seen this please read it thoroughly and you will understand . . . https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/TwinParadox/twin_paradox.html

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker said “I want to clarify the statement ‘As path through spacetime is shorter than Bs.’ When we say this, we are performing the calculations with a preferred frame, as doing the same calculations in B's frame will give us the opposite answer”. This is simply false. The calculation is frame invariant. It doesn’t matter whose frame you use. There is no preferred frame

Comment: @Dale Looks like I should do the calculations then.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the cause of the asymmetric ageing in the twin paradox. It  arises because the twins follow asymmetric paths through spacetime. In the modified example, in which the stay-at-home twin has a kink in their worldline, the paths are still asymmetric, and the asymmetric ageing follows.  The factor you are missing out is that when twin B reaches the turnaround point, her shift to a new  frame of reference causes a change in the orientation of her time axis and a corresponding tilt in the direction of her planes of simultaneity. The effect of this tilt increases with distance, so the fact that twin B's acceleration occurs at a greater distance than twin A's is the cause of the asymmetry.

Indeed, the acceleration, per se, is not required to cause the effect. There is a version of the paradox in which there is no acceleration- twin B simply hands off a time reading to a inertial third traveller, C, who is heading back to Earth. The more general case is that a person coasting between two events will always record a longer elapsed time that an observer who follows another path that is not a straight line, owing to the geometry of spacetime. The role of acceleration is that it allows one to follow a curved or kinked path- it is the path that causes the effect, not the acceleration per se.

Comment: Would you say the clock that is handed off from twin B to traveller C does not accelerate during the transfer? 
Or does traveller C only take a look at B's clock? But then C has to accelerate towards Earth, right? So acceleration is again playing a role.

Comment: @GeertVS no there is no need for the same clock to be involved. Let's call tB the time experienced by traveller B on the outward leg, and tC the time experienced by traveller C on the return leg. The sum of tB and tC will be less than the time experienced between B's departure and C's arrival.

Comment: @MarcoOcram The triplet paradox seems to be a blatant misnomer, since twin A can simply hand off its time to a traveller D who is heading towards B. In this case, both A and B will agree that the other is younger without violating SR. The paradox only arises when both A and B come back to the same spot and become stationary, since there must be only one true answer/reality of who is older.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker it is _not_ a paradox, it is _precisely_ how things are supposed to work!

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker there are no paradoxes in SR, only misunderstandings. So the twin paradox is a misnomer, as is the pole-in-the-barn paradox etc.  The relativity of simultaneity accounts for all of the effects in which A and B  are moving relative to each other and not co-located.

Comment: Can't we say acceleration gets you into a potential of curved spacetime, just as gravitational acceleration does? And the duration in this potential scales with the length of the journey. 
As for the remarks about paradoxes: mind that a paradox is not a contradiction, only a seeming contradiction. So a good theory can paradoxically describe how things work.

Comment: @GeertVS I think it is best we don't say anything unless we can back it up with solid theory.

Comment: @m4r35n357 I'd rather share ideas that could be wrong than stay silent, waiting for a new full-fledged theory

Comment: There is no new theory to wait for, the one we have is fine!

Comment: I think this might be very important if we are going to make something like a warp drive, which I think we need to if we want to survive long term as a species.

Comment: @GeertVS It has nothing to do with acceleration. It is a property of the geometry of spacetime, Just as a crooked path is longer than a straight path in 3d space. You need acceleration to follow a crooked path, but it is not acceleration that makes the crooked path longer.

Comment: Likewise a crooked path in 4d spacetime in shorter, in time, than a straight one. You need acceleration to follow such a path, but it is the path itself which is shorter in time.

Comment: @MarcoOcram well in boths comments you admit "you need acceleration" so how can it not have anything to do with acceleration? We agree on the rest :)

The whole paradox is about reversing the roles, as this picture nicely sums up:
https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55809d94e4b041b423dad36b/1484788015963-KV6QIHXY35JCNSV637JD/image-asset.png

While obviously only one of them can be younger than the other:
https://www1.phys.vt.edu/~takeuchi/relativity/notes/twin.gif

And the one who accelerated takes the path of shortest time (and hence is youngest).

Comment: @GeertVS you seem to be deliberately missing my point. Acceleration is a red herring. There is a well-known variant of the twin paradox that does not involve acceleration at all.

Comment: @MarcoOcram if you co-move with the twin in the spaceship, then it's the twin on Earth that has a kink in his/her worldline. 
We agree that acceleration is not the only factor in the amount of time-dilation. Thats why I think acceleration gets one into a (gravitational) potential, and the duration in the potential scales with the amount of time-dilation. While observers are separated things might not seem to check out, but they do when observer (re)unite.

Comment: @GeertVS you are straightforwardly wrong. In SR, the difference in elapsed time between two events depends on the path taken between them, and is determined by the geometry of spacetime. But best of luck with developing your ideas!

Comment: @MarcoOcram how would you describe the path of the twin in the spaceship from the reference frame of a co-moving origin? 
The geometry of spacetime is Minkowski, ignoring the small gravitational potential of the Earth.

Comment: @GeertVS I don't know what you mean exactly.

Comment: @GeertVS well there you go - world lines are not relative!  There is no kink for the non-traveler.